# How to use datepicker.min.js?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

On my site I load datepicker.min.js

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://xxx/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://xxx/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/datepicker.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({"closeText":"Fermer","currentText":"Aujourd\u2019hui","monthNames":["janvier","f\u00e9vrier","mars","avril","mai","juin","juillet","ao\u00fbt","septembre","octobre","novembre","d\u00e9cembre"],"monthNamesShort":["Jan","F\u00e9v","Mar","Avr","Mai","Juin","Juil","Ao\u00fbt","Sep","Oct","Nov","D\u00e9c"],"nextText":"Suivant","prevText":"Pr\u00e9c\u00e9dent","dayNames":["dimanche","lundi","mardi","mercredi","jeudi","vendredi","samedi"],"dayNamesShort":["dim","lun","mar","mer","jeu","ven","sam"],"dayNamesMin":["D","L","M","M","J","V","S"],"dateFormat":"MM d, yy","firstDay":1,"isRTL":false});});
</script>
```

So I wish to add a datepicker to my input

```
<input type="text" class="mkdf-filter-min-date" name="min_date" placeholder="Check-in:" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $today ) ?>"/>
```

But i don't find how to do.

Comment: you have to add JavaScript to bind the input tag to the datepicker : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: and how do you do this ?

Comment: i found my solution, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i got it, i was adding it to input name & not input class !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.mkdf-filter-min-date').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
</script>
```